# Fault-tolerant NFS?

Tags: linux, nfs, fault-tolerance

Probably a FAQ but I haven't found anything useful after a while of searching:

Can I set up NFS in such a way that every single error (e.g. server CPU, hard disk, hd controller, network adapter, network cable, power supply) is masked without any need for immediate intervention?

I have only answers for parts of the problem: RAID, redundant power supply, redundant network adapters

How do I address CPU failure of the NFS server so that clients fail over transparently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could buy a system that can tollerate a CPU failure, or you could implement more than one server. You can create an NFS failover cluster fairly easily on Linux (I'm sure Sun et all have a mechanism for this too).

A fairly well supported/common way to do it is with heartbeat, ([first link I found on Google, search NFS and heartbeat](http://www.howtoforge.com/highly-available-nfs-server-using-drbd-and-heartbeat-on-debian-5.0-lenny)) to manage the cluster and then share the storage between the servers. The important thing to do with NFS to ensure a transparent failover is to also share the NFS state information which is usually in /var/lib/nfs. You can do that by putting it on the shared storage.

edit: Also setting the fsid option to the same value on the NFS export on each server will prevent you from getting stale file handles when the cluster fails over.

Comment: Pacemaker + Heartbeat (or Corosync these days) + DRBD + NFS is what works for me.

Comment: Howtoforge has a tutorial on setting this up as well:  http://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_nfs_drbd_heartbeat

Answer (score 4):

nfs 4.1 supports pNFS, which is clustered. http://www.pnfs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Nfs standard server in a active/active configuration is impossible as I know,is possible a active/passive cluster(tested using hearthbeat+nfs3).
Here's a nice how to, fast and simple using
[Setting Up A Highly Available NFS Server | howtoforge.com](https://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_nfs_drbd_heartbeat)

Is also possible to setup an active/active nfs4 cluster using glusterfs+haproxy+keepalived+ganesha-nfs.

Answer (score -3):

Partners of Nexenta Systems offer clustered solutions that are ideal for making for highly available NFS, while taking full advantage of ALL available features of ZFS. Typical model calls for a 2-node cluster with a shared storage unit, configured as a JBOD. NexentaStor is used to provision NFS, CIFS, etc. In your case it may just be NFS. Our clustering framework allows for a highly-available solution that might be exactly what you are looking for.